# Are there standard iphone tab bar icons for 'home' and 'info'?

Tags: iphone, standard-icons

I'm putting together an iphone app which has a tab bar controller as its root controller.  Two of the tabs we want are 'Home' and 'Information'; it seems like those ought to be standard icons, but I don't see an option for that in the interface builder.  Are there standard iphone tab bar icons for 'home' and 'info', and if so how do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Home and Information are not available as standard for Tabs. you can download icons to create a custom tab though - see here [clicky](http://glyphish.com/)